# Calling Par(NEW=True) with no plot after running 2 plot commands

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-bigquery

```
library(bigrquery)
install.packages('readr')
project <- "grab-analysis" # put your project ID here
taxiQuery <- "SELECT ROUND(pickup_latitude, 4) as lat,
                ROUND(pickup_longitude, 4) as long, COUNT(*) as
num_pickups FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_2016` WHERE
(pickup_latitude BETWEEN 40.61 AND 40.91) AND
(pickup_longitude BETWEEN -74.06 AND -73.77 ) GROUP
BY lat, long"
taxiQuery1 <- "SELECT ROUND(pickup_latitude, 4) as lat,
                ROUND(pickup_longitude, 4) as long, COUNT(*) as
num_pickups FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_green_trips_2016` WHERE
(pickup_latitude BETWEEN 40.61 AND 40.91) AND
(pickup_longitude BETWEEN -74.06 AND -73.77 ) GROUP
BY lat, long"    

taxi_df <- query_exec(taxiQuery, project = project, max_pages = Inf,use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
taxi_df1 <- query_exec(taxiQuery1, project = project, max_pages = Inf,use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
require(ggplot2)

taxi_plot <- ggplot(data=taxi_df, aes(x = long, y = lat))
    taxi_plot1 <- ggplot(data=taxi_df1, aes(x=long,y=lat))
    final_plot = taxi_plot + geom_point(aes(alpha = as.factor(num_pickups)),size=0.4, color="white") + 
    scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.1,1), guide = FALSE) +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="black", color="black"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            axis.text = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
            axis.title = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            plot.background = element_rect(fill="black", color="black"))
    plot(taxi_plot1 + geom_point(aes(alpha = as.factor(num_pickups)),
                            size=0.4, color="green") +scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.1,1), guide = FALSE))
```

I was trying to plot the taxi pick up points of both types of taxi on the same plot as represented by `taxi_df` and `taxi_df1`. However, I got an error saying that `par(new = TRUE) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot` after using par(new=TRUE).

I cant seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: You can't mix base R `plot` & `ggplot` like that. Remove `plot` in the last line

Comment: Could you post that as an answer, @Tung ? For future reference of the community.

Comment: @Mangu: the problem is we don't have the `taxi_df` to reproduce the plot

Comment: I've added the taxi_df part. My apologies